# Criar um codificador/decodificador simples em Java

Tags: javascript

**eu preciso criar um codificador e decodificador onde**

```
e = enter 
i = imes
a = ai
o = ober
u = ufat
```

**assim qualquer palavra escrita, vai ser codificada ou decodificada*

Answer (score 0):

use o método replaceAll para substituir todas letras que você está buscando na string, pela palavra de sua preferência.

Exemplo:

```
String s1="java";  
String replaceString=s1.replaceAll("a","e");
```

Conteúdo de `replaceString` = jeve